# firebase snapshot json object as text not as object in vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I can pull the data but it prints this as an object in my view:

```
{ "-MH8EpUbn1Eu3LdT0Tj0": { "code": "https://www.apesyntax.com", "content": "This is the tut content", "date": "2020-09-13", "email": "test", "first": "tester guy", "language": [ "VUE" ], "last": "testing", "picture": "", "title": "Get data from json to Ruby object ", "userID": "3DSOrtpBHlYENn14bE9UJKWly4G3" }, "-MH8TRc3NfinUtI-XORZ": { "code": "https://www.codepen.io/apesyntax/pen/ExKNawv", "content": "asdad asd asd a", "date": "2020-09-13", "email": "test@tester", "first": "tester", "language": [ "Ruby", "Python" ], "last": "asda", "picture": "", "title": "Add a new tutorial!", "userID": "3DSOrtpBHlYENn14bE9UJKWly4G3" } }
```

The created function i use to pull the data from fire base db is :

```html
<template>
  <v-container id="tutshow">
    <h1>Tutorials</h1>

    {{authUser.favoriteFood }}
    {{authUser.myTutorialTitle }}
  </v-container>
</template>
```

```js
import firebase from '../plugins/firebase'
import vue from 'vue'

let db = firebase.database();
let usersRef = db.ref('users');
let tutRef = db.ref('tutorials');

export default {
    name: 'tutShow',
    data() {
        return {
            authUser: '',
            favoriteFood: null,
            myTutorialTitle: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    created: function() {
      data => console.log(data.user,data.tutorials, data.credential.accessToken)
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          this.authUser = user
          if (user) {
            usersRef.child(user.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.val()) {
              this.favoriteFood = snapshot.val().favoriteFood
              vue.set(this.authUser, 'favoriteFood', this.favoriteFood)
               }
            })
            tutRef.child(user.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.val()) {
              this.myTutorialTitle = snapshot.val()
              vue.set(this.authUser, 'myTutorialTitle', this.myTutorialTitle )
               }
            });
          }

       })
     }
   }
      // The Example beneath fetch json directly from firebase
        //this.$http.get('https://apesyntax.firebaseio.com/tutorials.json')
        //.then(response => response.json())
        //    .then(data => {
        //        let list = [];
        //        for (let key in data) {
        //            list.push({
        //                ...data[key],
        //                    id: key
        //            })
        //        }
        //        console.log(list)
        //        this.tutorials = list;
        //    })
```

If we observe in the result beneath we can appreciate the first call being printed as text "Potatos" but the next one is printed as an object:

[image: Json object view printed as object example picture]

I wonder how can I print this better.

Comment: as you can see i tried to get the titles to test so if possible then I could pull the rest of the data not sure like into a v-loop or something so far I am proud of pulling that data as an object but I want to have a clearer visualization of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, it looks like your tutorial reference returns an object. In order to display it properly, you should iterate its properties

```html
<template>
  <v-container id="tutshow">
    <h1>Tutorials</h1>

    <p class="tagline">{{authUser.favoriteFood }}</p>

    <!-- loop over the tutorials -->
    <div v-for="(tutorial, key) in authUser.myTutorialTitle" :key="key">
      <h2>{{ tutorial.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ tutorial.content }}</p>
      <!-- and so on -->
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

---

Now on to some improvements.

In these two lines...

```js
vue.set(this.authUser, 'favoriteFood', this.favoriteFood)

// and

vue.set(this.authUser, 'myTutorialTitle', this.myTutorialTitle)
```

You're treating `this.authUser` like an object but in your `data` initialiser, you've set it to be an empty string.

Start by setting `authUser` to be an object.

```js
data:() => ({
  authUser: {}
})
```

*Note: I didn't see any reason to duplicate `favoriteFood` and `myTutorialTitle` as top-level data properties.*

Now in your `onAuthStateChanged` callback, you can read data and build up your `authUser`

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
  if (user) {
    // fetch user and tutorial refs in parallel
    const [ userSnapshot, tutorialSnapshot ] = await Promise.all([
      usersRef.child(user.uid).once("value"),
      tutRef.child(user.uid).once("value")
    ])

    // Now construct your full "authUser" object
    this.authUser = {
      ...user,
      favoriteFood: userSnapshot.val()?.favoriteFood,
      myTutorialTitle: tutorialSnapshot.val()?.myTutorialTitle
    }
  }
})
```

See [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if that `?.` syntax is new to you.

Comment: Thanks, Phill, you gave me a solution, this will get me going again, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Do you know how could I iterate a way to obtain all of the object's data from all the users inside the tutorials object?

Comment: @Abraham I saw your other question and no, I don't know at the moment. I suspect you'd need to make a query